# Dynamic Textfields in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

All -

New to struts2 here.. I've been reading some tutorials, and even picked up a book so I understand some, but please forgive me if I use the wrong terms.

I'm looking for an example or an explanation on how to create a dynamic list of text fields based on a collection, have the user enter some input and then assign that input back to the object.

Example:

I have a dynamic set of products, I'd like to be able to display a table of product names and textfields where the user can enter a price for that product.

```
Product1 ....... [ textfield_price1 ]
Product2 ....... [ textfield_price2 ]
...
ProductN

[submit_button ]
```

How do I then map those textfield values back to each product, most of the examples I have seen are standard forms with static information.

Can anyone point me to the right place ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you'd use map-based syntax, usually with an ID as the key, and a domain object as the value. This is covered in the [type conversion](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-CollectionandMapSupport) docs.

**Nutshell:** the action has a map of `{ ID => Product }` for the form data:

```
public Map<Long, Product> getProductMap() { ... }
// and setter, and private property
```

Use `[] in the JSP with an ID as the`name` attribute value:

```
<s:textfield name="productMap[%{id}]" ... />
```

You could iterate over a collection of products, a pre-filled map, etc.